# How to test if a Perl CGI::Cookie cookie is almost about to expire?

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

If the cookie is between `0` and `x` minutes away from expiration, I would like to refresh the `expires` value of that cookie to some set value (if the cookie is already expired, I do not want to refresh it).

How would I accomplish this with `CGI::Cookie` and `CGI.pm`?

Comment: [So you don't want to test it if the cookie is not about to expire?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=whether)

Comment: @Alex: But how will you know, without testing?!

Comment: I will know it is not about to expire, Tomalak, because I will test the expiration value, and if the value that returns is greater than some threshold, then I know the cookie is not about to expire, based upon my definition of about-to-be-expired for this cookie. Clear?

Comment: @AlexReynolds: I think you might have completely misinterpreted my not-so-subtle dig at your wording. Oh well.

Comment: No, I understood you perfectly, Tomalak. If you don't want to answer the question, please feel free to move on to questions that interest you. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexReynolds: Actually you completely didn't. Anyway, I shall take you up on your kind offer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies sent by the browser do not expose their expiration time; they are either sent or they aren't.  To know when it is going to expire, you have to store the expiration time in the cookie value in some parseable form.

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie has been set, then it will be sent to the server. If it has expired, then it won't be.

Just test to see if the cookie exists, and refresh it if it exists.

Comment: I would like to refresh the cookie if its expiration time is between certain values. Do you know how I might accomplish this? Thanks!